# Simulate back from sleep condition for web app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, electron

I have an web application that is always connected (through websockets) and I need to debug some issues when the computer comes back from sleep/hibernate. I've been putting the laptop to sleep and awake every time, but that is slow and error prone.

Does anyone have some ideas on how to simulate this condition without having to sleep the computer?'

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You could switch off the wifi/network, that should work

Comment: My problem is that I "detect" when you don't have network (aka turning off wifi) and trigger an explicit reconnection flow when network comes back. But sleep, does not cause the network to appear as offline to the application, even though it is, so when it comes back, the app thinks is still connected. I'm trying to optimize the reconnection flows for that specific case.

Comment: please paste some code with what your trying!